# Canceling a Process started via System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

Tags: c#

I am writing an application where I have a Process running in a `BackgroundWorker`.  I would like to support cancellation from the user interface, but I don't see an easy way to do this.

The `Process` is actually a fairly long running command line exe.  The output is getting redirected asynchronously via the `Progress.OutputDataReceived` event and is being used to report progress to the GUI.

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        //...

        process.Start()

        //...

        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}

private void CancelWorker()
{
    worker.CancelAsync();
    // where to actually listen for the cancellation???
}
```

There doesn't appear to be a way to have the process "listen" for any input from the main thread aside from the `StandardInput`, but that won't work unless the app itself will response to a specific input to abort.

Is there a way to cancel a process based on a cancel request from the main thread?

For the purposes of my of the EXE running in the process, I can just call `Process.Close()` to exit without any side-effects, but the `Process` object is only known to the `worker_DoWork()` method, so I'll need to keep track of the `Process` instance for cancellation purposes... that's why I'm hoping there might be a better way.

(if it matters, I am targeting .NET 3.5 for compatibility issues.)

Comment: Is there a reason you're starting a process in a BG worker? It's generally a call that doesn't take a long time (the program being launched may take a while to load, but that will be in its own process).

Comment: It's actually not in a background worker, but in a custom Async method, `BackgroundWorker` seemed simpler for describing the situation.  But the reason is this is part of a larger process that is running in a background thread.

Comment: CancelAsync won't work because the thread has finished its job within a few milliseconds, unless you have some heavy load within that `DoWork` method. Although `using` is good practice, since you need to be able to access the `Process` from elsewhere in the code, you could have a class-level variable to hold the `Process` and call `Process.Close` on that. Just remember to call `Dispose` on the process when your thread returns or the process is no longer needed.

Comment: The exe running in `Process` is fairly long running command line tool that I'm trying to execute from within my application... on average, it can take 15 minutes or more to complete.  One of the reasons it is running in an async method is to allow for progress reporting.  I can't report progress directly from the `process_OutputDataReceived` event handler since it is on a different thread, so an async method seemed like a logical choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For cooperative cancellation, you need to listen to [BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending.aspx)
  in [BackgroundWorker.DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx)
 event.

[How to: Use a Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        //...

        process.Start()

        //...
        while(true)
        { 
            if ((sender as BackgroundWorker).CancellationPending && !process.HasExited)
            {
              process.Kill();
              break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
         }

        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, however because of the `while(true)`, the loop never exits unless a cancellation is received.  I changed it to `while(!process.HasExited)` and it works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try this, this might be help you, in easy way

```
private System.Threading.TimerCallback worker;
private System.Threading.Timer workertimer ;
private void worker_DoWork()
{
   //You codes
}
private void StartWorker()
{
   worker = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(worker_DoWork);
   workertimer = new System.Threading.Timer(worker, null, 1000, 1000);
}

private void CancelWorker()
{
    worker.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I donot see, how `process` is Killed in `Dispose` method. How can it work?